# Python error: none_dealloc: deallocating None: bug likely caused by a refcount error in a C extension Python runtime state: initialized

Tags: python, gdal

So I'm using python 3.11 and the GDAL python bindings to iterate through a shapefile.

All of a sudden the code, many upon many iterations in throws the following error and terminates:

> Fatal Python error: none_dealloc: deallocating None: bug likely caused by a refcount error in a C extension
> Python runtime state: initialized

> Current thread 0x00007f3ce2f9d740 (most recent call first):

The line number changes, but seems to be happening for some reason where a collection variable would either be set or deleted.

It first died at the following line:

> points = geom.GetPoints()

Having kind of guessed that it would have something to do with the collection being either set or freed I added the following line at the end of the loop, still in scope:

> del points

Now the code dies there after many upon many iterations of the loop.

I can only think it has something to do with threading, any thoughts ? is there a way to lock the object just in case ?

Comment: where is the code ?  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I ended up discovering that this is an issue in the geometry class itself. The item itself was a polygon containing a linear ring sub shape. If you called getpoints on it without obtaining a reference to its child geometry it would produce the listed error.

Comment: When it should just return an empty array for example without throwing any fatal error

Comment: @D.L you guys can close this but it is a relevant answer I added.

Comment: @JackAssim I removed the meta commentary from your answer. Questions about bugs in popular libraries are absolutely on-topic on this site. This question wouldn't be closed just because the answer is "it's a bug".

Comment: That said, this question would still benefit from some editing to clarify exactly what code causes this problem and with what version(s) of the GDAL bindings. As it stands, it's less likely to be useful to future visitors, since it's hard to recolonize what the problem is or how to reproduce it.

Comment: @Brian61354270 see the answer i added, i could always move it into the question and close it I suppose.  It appears its a 'you're not calling this from c/c++  but we're still going to treat you like a c/c++ programmer and break your shitty code which should not really break, but we're being sticklers' sort of error. there are logically points in the object, i suppose in the case of a multipolygon this could be a problem, but for a polygon shape this wouldn't seem to be, anyway, it breaks because it contains a sub-class instance with points.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug in the GDAL bindings.   When the geometry class is being polled for points, if it contains no points or contains a subclass containing points, its throwing this error. You have to check the geometry type or it will bomb as shown for some strange reason instead of the class code checking itself and seeing if the data related to points is empty or just simply returning the first encapsulated class instance's point data instead or an empty collection.

In the case of my script this happens with an enveloping geometry instance of type "POLYGON", wherein the points are contained in a sublayer of type "LINEARRING", which you retrieve by a call as follows:

```
polygon:ogr.Geometry  = feature.GetGeometryRef()
linearring:ogr.Geometry = polygon.GetGeometryRef(0)

# this is what throws the error
nonexistent_points = polygon.GetPoints()

# this is what works
encapsulate_classes_points = linearring.GetPoints()
```

I do seem to remember a discussion with another person versed in gdal who pointed out that in the case of a multi-polygon the breaking behavior makes sense, personally I feel that in a higher level language like python, you could just throw an exception for that specific scenario since it really should be the only one, or simply return a list of lists would probably be more appropriate otherwise returning None/Empty/Null.